# "whitespace-sensitive" property significance in search

Tags: marklogic

Please tell me in detail the significance of "whitespace-sensitive" property in search query. I am executing below query on query console and get no result.

`cts.elementValues(["product"],"",["collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint","ascending"],cts.notQuery(cts.elementValueQuery(xs.QName("product"),"*","whitespace-sensitive")));`

But if I remove the query which has "whitespace-sensitive" property set, I get the proper result.

`cts.elementValues(["product"],"",["collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint","ascending"]);`

I believe this might be because of some improper data. Hence want to know, which scenarios can fail "whitespace-sensitive" property search.

Comment: The first query is looking for all values of "product" that are on fragments that don't have any value for "product". What results do you expect?

Comment: I'm not going to answer this in the answer section because it would be re-stating what benW said... cts.elementValues gives back strings from a lexicon. These are expanded into a word query in MarkLogic. This leaves you with a query: fragments that have the word product (as extracted from the range index)  - restricted to fragments without the word 'product'. You have built a query which can never match results. I suggest you re-write an eample where you prove that it is the whitesafe-sensitive  option as the cause and not the removal of a whole query.